# Sylow Theorems for Symmetric (Permutation) Groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The General Linear Group $GL(n,\mathbb{F}_p)$ has an interesting property that the proof of Sylow theorem for this group can be given which is based on the natural action of this group on the $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$. A short sketch of proof is:

1) The [group of upper uni-triangular matrices](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Unitriangular_matrix_group) over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a Sylow-p subgroup.

2) $GL(n,\mathbb{F}_p)$ acts on the collection $\mathcal{F}=\{0\subseteq V_1\subseteq V_2\cdots \subseteq V_n\}$ of chains, where $V_i$ is $i$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$, and the Stabilizers of chains which induce identity map on quotient $V_i/V_{i-1}$ are precisely the Sylow-$p$ subgroups; Sylow-$p$ subgroups are conjugate.

3) The number of Sylow-$p$ subgroups is equal to the number of chains in above collection(my guess); and it can be shown easily by combinatorics that $|\mathcal{F}|\equiv 1(p)$.

The details are given in the book of Alperin-Bell, Groups and Representations.

**Question:** Instead of $GL(n,\mathbb{F}_p)$, consider the family of symmetric (permutation) groups $S_n$. Can we prove Sylow theorems for this group in some similar way as done for $GL(n,\mathbb{F}_p)$?

The existence of Sylow-p subgroup in $S_n$ is already done by Cauchy, which is expressed by "wreath product", and a proof is given in Herstein-Topics in Algebra. But I couldn't see (or prove) their "conjugacy" and "cardinality is $1$ mod $p$"

[Here, I want to see a proof without following the arguments of any well known proof of Sylow theorems for arbitrary finite groups.]

Comment: But that special case deals with only one prime, so it does not quite give the full theorem. Which prime could be singled out like that for symmetric groups?

Comment: You can embed $S_n$ to $Gl(n,p)$ , Can it be helpful ?

Comment: I think, for arbitrary $n\geq 2$, there is a well known description of a Sylow-$p$ subgroup of $Sn$ for any prime $p$ dividing $n!$. Rotman gives much details of this in his book on Group Theory.

Comment: @ Mesel: In think it will not be. If we embed $S_n$ in $GL_n$ and try to proceed, I think we will travel with same directions as in the proof of Sylow theorem given by G. A. Miller (or whoever) [he proves Sylow theorems for $S_n$ and then for arbitrary finite groups by embedding them in $S_n$].